# How do I use ThreadLocalTargetSource in a TaskDecorator?

Tags: java, spring, java-threads, thread-local, spring-async

We are using Spring's ThreadLocalTargetSource to set some Tenant context information into a bean and propagate it through a typical HTTP request or received event. The approach is similar to what is described in:

https://dzone.com/articles/an-alternative-approach-to-threadlocal-using-sprin-1

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
public ThreadLocalTargetSource threadLocalTenantContext() {
    ThreadLocalTargetSource result = new ThreadLocalTargetSource();
    result.setTargetBeanName("tenantContext");
    return result;
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "proxiedThreadLocalTargetSource")
public ProxyFactoryBean proxiedThreadLocalTargetSource(ThreadLocalTargetSource threadLocalTargetSource) {
    ProxyFactoryBean result = new ProxyFactoryBean();
    result.setTargetSource(threadLocalTargetSource);
    return result;
}
```

However, I now need to use a TaskExecutor to run some process asynchronously and I'm not sure how to send that tenant information into the newly spawned threads. Using `TaskDecorator` it would be simple to get information from MDC into the new thread:

```
// Set this in taskExecutor.setDecorator(...)
public class TenantContextThreadDecorator implements TaskDecorator {

    @Override
    public Runnable decorate(Runnable runnable) {
        final Map<String, String> mdc = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        return () -> {
            try {
                MDC.setContextMap(mdc);
                runnable.run();
            } finally {
                MDC.clear();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to get the TenantContext to set that on the runnable.